# Remove 'There are no articles in this category.' Text

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, language, category

Joomla 3.9.14

I have a category with no articles, although the sub categories **do** contain articles.

```
 - colours (no articles)
 -- red (1 article)
 -- blue (2 articles)
```

I have a menu type `Category Blog` that links to my `colours` category. On this page the following text is displayed;

> There are no articles in this category. If subcategories display on
>   this page, they may have articles.

Is it possible to remove this text completely? I'd rather not change language files or modify css.

I expected there to be a default Joomla setting to hide this text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got to;

content > articles > options > category tab > No Articles Message > hide / show

Comment: Great answer. Only thing I'd add (merely for completeness' sake) is a note that this only works if the menu item for the category page in question has not been set to override the defaults, if it has (or if you only want to eliminate the No Articles message on this one page) you need to open the menu item, go to the category tab and set "No Articles Message" there. Whatever is set on the menu item overrides the defaults, unless it's set to "Use Global"

Answer (score 1):

Disable `No Articles Message` option in the menu item or in `com_content` configuration.